# WinDbg search option shows no output

Tags: debugging, search, output, byte, windbg

WinDbg shows no output when I try to search with -b option.

```
    kd> s -b 0b590000 0b605000 0x4d
```

But when I search for dwords or use db command I get results.
db output:

```
    kd> db 0b590000 L8
    0b590000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00                          MZ......
```

search for dwords output:

```
    kd> s -d 0b590000 0b605000 00905a4d
    0b590000  00905a4d 00000003 00000004 0000ffff  MZ..............
```

Comment: @AndyLuhrs asks: What version of Windbg are you using and what OS are you targeting?

Comment: don't seem to be the case with 6.2.9200 in an xp vm may be it is a bug that crept in some latest version  in fact dword shouldnt output anything because s  is documented to return results properly aligned  send feedback to windbg team  with version , os etc  lkd> s -b nt l1 'M'
804d7000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 MZ..............
lkd> s -b nt l1 0x4d
804d7000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
lkd> s -w nt l1 0x5a4d
804d7000  5a4d 0090 0003 0000 0004 0000 ffff 0000  MZ..............
lkd> s -w nt l1 0x4d
lkd> s -d nt l1 0x4d
lkd> s -d nt l4 0x4d
lkd> s -d nt l10 0x4d

Comment: Could not reproduce with old versions 6.12 and 6.6 either

Comment: I tested this on 6.11 and 6.12 versions of WinDbg. Host system is Windows 10. And target is Windows XP on VirtualBox.